# usage of conceive

Tags: vocabulary

The online dictionary, freedictionary.com, gives several definitions of the verb, *conceive*.

> 1. To become pregnant with
> 2. To form or develop in the mind
> 3. To apprehend mentally; understand
> 4. To be of the opinion that; think
> 5. To begin or originate in a specific way

I am interested in the **second** definition. Next, I am going to use it in a sentence:

> It took me at least thirty minutes to **conceive** a good thesis statement for my essay.

Is it correct to say *conceive a thesis statement*?

Comment: Yes, but we would ***tend*** to use the phrasal verb: come up with a good thesis statement.

Comment: @Lambie I agree, but I think that's because *conceive* sounds a bit formal, whereas the surrounding text appears to be informal in style (and not because it co-occurs with *a thesis statement*). Am I on the right track? People don't normally talk about conceiving something themselves, do they? The idiom *come up with* is markedly informal, in my view, and therefore suitable for conversational English. *I cannot conceive...* on the other hand sounds elevated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your sentence is grammatical and makes perfect sense. This usage of **conceive** basically means "to invent or devise" a plan, an idea, or an invention. It is synonymous with "to think up", "to come up with." For example:

> That script was conceived and written by Spielberg.
>
> The project was conceived in the 1990s, but wasn't carried out until 2004.

Answer (score 0):

One conceives a plan, a project, a program, a book. a film. Something that is long or long-ish.

**I would not say to conceive a statement**. Personal choice.